# Shell Script in Linux gets rake aborted! No Rakefile found but works not running from shell

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I am trying to run this script which works fine from a prompt but fails in a shell script:

```
rake redmine:email:receive_imap unknown_user=accept no_permission_check=1 RAILS_ENV="production" host=mail.domain.org port=993 username=helpdesk@domain.org password=XXXXXX ssl=1 move_on_success=Processed move_on_failure=Failed project=emailsupport tracker=Support subject=EmailSupport status=New
```

Here is the .sh file that I am trying to run with sh /opt/redmine/scripts/redmine-rake-email.sh and am getting rake aborted! No Rakefile found and I am running this in the /opt/redmine directory that does have a Rakefile.

*edited* Actually my script looks like this now. Still does not work.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=$PATH:/opt/redmine:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin
cd /opt/redmine 
rake redmine:email:receive_imap unknown_user=accept no_permission_check=1 RAILS_ENV="production" host=mail.domain.org port=993 username=helpdesk@domain.org password=XXXXXX ssl=1 move_on_success=Processed move_on_failure=Failed project=emailsupport tracker=Support subject=EmailSupport status=New
```

Here is my PATH when I run echo $PATH:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/opt/redmine:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/bin
```

I am stuck and not sure what is wrong. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you really have spaces in the PATH line in your script?

Comment: No, I sure don't. I accidently put them in above when I typed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-f /opt/redmine/Rakefile` to the rake arguments just after `rake`.

Comment: Thank you Tass, I did that and now it says 'rake aborted! development database is not configured'. Why would it refer to development?

Comment: Ok, read that rake defaults to development so I put RAILS_ENV=production right after that and now I am getting rake aborted! Connection refused - connect(2). I just can't get a break. :)

Comment: This is working now. In the script, I removed the PATH settings and also the rake command ended up with a line feed in it. Removed that also and now it is working. Thanks to Tass for having me put in the -f /opt/redmine/Rakefile. That actually fixed my issue.